# Best way to backup million of assets? weekly changing (adding only) using Bash Script?

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

I am currently setting up a website including a CMS which has millions of assets. Smaller and bigger pictures mainly.
I would like to backup these files on a regular basis. For example weekly.
I have an FTP mounted to my machine to which I can copy to. Yesterday I thought about using rsync and simply copy only the new files. But it seems to take a bit long for rsync to crawl through all the files.
Basically it takes ages because the FTP storage is shitty. 
So I ended up with the idea to find only the latest modified (last 24h) files in my assets directory and copy them to the FTP. To minimize the load on the FTP.
But I am new to bash scripting, of course google helped me already and I came up with the following parts:

```
#!/bin/bash

Source="/my/source/folder"
Destination="/my/slow/ftp/"

ls find $Source -mtime -1 -ls
    do
        cp -a $Source $Destination
done
```

What am I missing? Can you help me to finish it?

If my idea of backing up the delta is not optimal, feel free to suggest something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using one go of `find`.

For tasks like this where time precision is necessary, use `-mmin` option of `find` to express the time constraint in minutes instead of `-mtime` to express in days.

```
find /source -mmin -1441 -exec cp -a -t /destination {} +
```

This will copy files, modified within the last 24 hours (1440 minutes) counting from now, from `/source` to `/destination`.

---

To copy to remote server, use `rsync`, as it will resume any partial transfer (unlike `scp`):

```
find /source -mmin -1441 -exec rsync -a {} user@host:/destination/ \;
```